# Why doesn't rust let me borrow `key_pressed` as mutable?

Tags: rust

I am trying to, when a key is pressed, keep it inside a vector. I do it like that :

```
fn main() {
    let mut file = open_file();

    log(&mut file, "test");

    let mut key_pressed: Vec<Keycode> = Vec::new();
    let device_state = DeviceState::new();
    let _guard = device_state.on_key_down(move |key| {
        println!("Down: {:#?}", key);
        key_pressed.push(key.clone());
    });

    loop {
        std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(1000));
    }
}
```

But when I compile, I get this error :

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow `key_pressed` as mutable, as it is a captured variable in a `Fn` closure
  --> src/main.rs:54:9
   |
54 |         key_pressed.push(key.clone());
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot borrow as mutable
```

As key_pressed is mutable, shouldn't I be able to borrow it ?
I do not understand why the fact that it's in a `Fn` closure should prevent me from borrowing it.

Comment: Please create [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

There are three function traits: [`Fn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Fn.html), [`FnMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FnMut.html), and [`FnOnce`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FnOnce.html). `FnOnce` requires ownership to be called, `FnMut` requires an `&mut` reference to be called, and `Fn` requires just a `&` reference to be called.

Usually when you see `Fn`, it means that this function will be called concurrently. For example, you can use a `Fn` here.

```rs
fn main() {
    let f = |a: i32| {
        println!("{a}");
    };

    std::thread::scope(|scope| {
        scope.spawn(|| {
            f(4);
        });
        scope.spawn(|| {
            f(3);
        });
    });
}
```

Each spawned closure holds `&f` and can call it using the `Fn` trait.

If you try to mutate something inside it, this will no longer compile.

```rs
fn main() {
    let mut all = Vec::new();
    let f = |a: i32| {
        all.push(a);
        println!("{a}");
    };

    std::thread::scope(|scope| {
        scope.spawn(|| {
            f(4);
        });
        scope.spawn(|| {
            f(3);
        });
    });
}
```

The solution is to use a type with [interior mutability](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-05-interior-mutability.html) like [`Mutex`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html), which will allow you to modify values while only holding a `&` reference.

```rs
use std::sync::Mutex;

fn main() {
    let all = Mutex::new(Vec::new());
    let f = |a: i32| {
        all.lock().unwrap().push(a);
        println!("{a}");
    };

    std::thread::scope(|scope| {
        scope.spawn(|| {
            f(4);
        });
        scope.spawn(|| {
            f(3);
        });
    });
}
```

Here's how that would work for your code.

```rs
let key_pressed: Mutex<Vec<Keycode>> = Mutex::default();
let device_state = DeviceState::new();
let _guard = device_state.on_key_down(move |key| {
    println!("Down: {:#?}", key);
    key_pressed.lock().unwrap().push(key.clone());
});
```

`Mutex` is also synchronized, so it implements `Sync` and can be used in multiple threads simultaneously. This usually needed since single-threaded code can usually use `FnMut`, but if not, you can use [`RefCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html), which is cheaper but still has interior mutability.